# jQuery Validate - at least one from a group of checkboxes is checked only if a radio button is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-validate

I´m using jquery validate plugin to ensure at least one from a group of three checkboxes is checked and it´s woking fine. But I want validate these checkboxes only if the radio button "Sim" is checked. I don´t know how to do this.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/TnmGr

**Html Form**:

```
<form name="itemForm" id="itemForm" method="post">
<p>
  <input name="resp01" type="radio" value="sim" id="resp01-sim" class="resp" /> <label for="resp01-sim">Sim</label>
  <input name="resp01" type="radio" value="não" id="resp01-nao" class="resp" /> <label for="resp01-nao">Não</label>
</p>
<fieldset style="width:200px"><legend>Outros catalogos</legend>
<input id="opt01" name="opt01" type="checkbox" value="true" class="require-one" />
<label for="opt01">opt01</label>
<input name="opt01" type="hidden" value="false" /><br />

<input id="opt02" name="opt02" type="checkbox" value="true" class="require-one" />
<label for="opt02">opt02</label>
<input name="river2" type="hidden" value="false" /><br />

<input id="opt03" name="opt03" type="checkbox" value="true" class="require-one" />
<label for="opt03">opt03</label>
<input name="opt03" type="hidden" value="false" /><br />
</fieldset>
<div class="error" id="form_error"></div>
<br />
<input type="submit" />
```

**JS**:

```
$.validator.addMethod('require-one', function(value) {
    return $('.require-one:checked').size() > 0;
}, 'Selecione pelo menos uma das opções.');

$(document).ready(function(){

    var checkboxes = $('.require-one');
    var checkbox_names = $.map(checkboxes, function(e, i) {
        return $(e).attr("name")
    }).join(" ");

    $("#itemForm").validate({
        groups: {
            checks: checkbox_names
        },
        rules: {
            resp01: 'required',
        },
        messages: {
            resp01:  { required: 'Selecione uma resposta!' },
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $('#form_error').append(error);
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('Form Submited');
            return false;
        }        

    });
});
```

Comment: You've made absolutely no attempt at this yourself.

Comment: @Sparky oh my god, of course! I was looking for the answer in the wrong place in the rules. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You simply need to alter the logic of your custom method.

```
$.validator.addMethod('require-one', function(value) {
    if ($('#resp01-sim').is(':checked')) {
        return $('.require-one:checked').size() > 0;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, 'Selecione pelo menos uma das opções.');
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/TnmGr/4/**

Comment: Your form is submitted if I check one checkbox and I unchecked it.

Comment: @AdrianP., that's only if you've selected the second `radio` button.  The checkboxes are only validated if a `radio` button is selected.  See the title of this question:  *"at least one from a group of checkboxes is checked **only if a radio button is checked**"*

Comment: True. My mistake. I didn't read the question in full. Just looked for a solution for something similar to do.

Comment: I dont Know the language but  validation works like charm Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

You could try the built-in functionality:

```
$( "#itemForm" ).validate({
  rules: {
    opt01: {
      required: "#resp01-sim"
    }
  }
});
```

http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/#example:-makes-details-required-only-if-#other-is-checked

Comment: I believe the user is asking for a solution for one checkbox to be required within a group of checkboxes.

Answer (score -1):

use the built in function of jquery validate
the require from group

```
$("#itemForm").validate({ 
 rules: {

opt01: {
   require_from_group: function () {
      if ($('#resp01-sim').is(':checked')) {
         return [1, ".require-one"]
      } else { return [0, ".require-one"] }
   },
},


opt02: {
   require_from_group: function () {
      if ($('#resp01-sim').is(':checked')) {
         return [1, ".require-one"]
      } else { return [0, ".require-one"] }
   },
},

opt03: {
   require_from_group: function () {
      if ($('#resp01-sim').is(':checked')) {
         return [1, ".require-one"]
      } else { return [0, ".require-one"] }
   },
},
}
});
```